# Google Ads error message when trying to change bid strategy

Tags: google-ads-api

So I have copied an existing campaign and set everything up for the new campaign, however, when I try to change the bid strategy from max. conversions to manual cpc I am getting this error message everytime.[Google Ads Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HKT0.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When Google posts these kinds of vague messages, I've found it's usually due to a multiplicity of issues (why they can't provide multiple error messages is beyond me.)

Do you have specific ad schedules?

Do you have call extensions scheduling or message extensions scheduling turned on?

Did the old campaign have adgroup-level bid strategies (pre Nov 2017)? I've had strangeness at the campaign level when this was set previously. To fix it, I've reset default bids at adgroup and cleared those at KW level, adjust campaign, and then go back in and adjust adgroup/kw where you want them.

Comment: Still a problem lol.  I think I solved mine by trying to edit something else, then it wanted me to verify that I was me via my pixel phone, then it worked. For some reason editing the target CPA didn't trigger this and just gave the vague error message above.